# типизация аргументов функции в паттерне roro

Tags: javascript, typescript

Наткнулся на паттерн [roro](https://habr.com/ru/post/472816/), захотел использовать его в typeScript, но столкнулся с проблемой как затипизировать аругменты функции

```
func({ foo: string, bar: myType }): void {}
```

но ts так разумеется не съедает типизацию, возможно ли вообще такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо явно объявлять тип объекта.

Например так

```
function func({ foo, bar }: { foo: string, bar: myType }): void {}
```

или отдельно интерфейс/тип

```
interface Params {
  foo: string;
  bar: myType;
}

function func({ foo, bar }: Params): void {}
```

Answer (score 0):

А можно и так:

[песочниц там](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAtiAq5oF4oEMB2IBQATCAxgDZoBO0AbmVAGYD2dAXFAM7CkCWGA5gDRQAjMsziJI2bKEi0ArhgIBGKKgAUAR2YBvWg2ZtOPfkNIiESKAF8AlMoB8UCnQ648hEuQfUacxc2-yFbH9FFW1jfno6SysJLmAIUho0AmhggCYobXUtHSZWdi4%20QWFYM2lrZkdnS2wCOgw2WXk0vx8M1W1Io2prO0ya9NDi0giGaOwgA)

```
type myType = any
declare var foo: string, bar: myType

type func1 = (q: { foo: string, bar: myType }) => void
declare var func1: func1
func1({ bar, foo })

interface func2 { (q: { foo: string, bar: myType }): void }
const func2: func2 = ({ foo, bar }) => { }
func2({ bar, foo })
```